# Web-Application to create organization/group website

Tags: webapp-rec

Suggest me a good, free, open source, downloadable web application in php to make a good website for a organization or group having more than one member. Only administrator(s) can change the content of the website. Please do not suggest me any forum/blog applications like WordPress, phpBB etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the better-supported open-source CMSes for this reason.

I would suggest either [Drupal](http://www.drupal.org) or Joomla, both written in PHP. I am a strong Drupal fan, but Joomla has a lot of supporters as well.

Just some main bullet-points from the [website of Drupal](http://drupal.org/features) to show how versatile/powerful it is:

> ### General features
>
> **Collaborative Book** - Our unique collaborative book feature lets you
>   setup a "book" and then authorize
>   other individuals to contribute
>   content.detailed information
>
> **Friendly URLs** - Drupal uses Apache's mod_rewrite to enable
>   customizable URLs that are both user
>   and search engine friendly.
>
> **Modules** - The Drupal community has contributed many modules which provide
>   functionality that extend Drupal
>   core.detailed information
>
> **Online help** - Like many Open Source projects, we can't say that our
>   online help is perfect but have built
>   a robust online help system built into
>   the core help text. Available to you
>   on your own site.detailed information
>
> **Open source** - The source code of Drupal is freely available under the
>   terms of the GNU General Public
>   License 2 (GPL). Unlike proprietary
>   blogging or content management
>   systems, Drupal's feature set is fully
>   available to extend or customize as
>   needed.detailed information
>
> **Personalization** - A robust personalization environment is at the
>   core of Drupal. Both the content and
>   the presentation can be individualized
>   based on user-defined preferences.
>
> **Role based permission system** - Drupal administrators don't have to
>   tediously setup permissions for each
>   user. Instead, they assign permissions
>   to roles and then group like users
>   into a role group.screenshot .
>   detailed information
>
> **Searching** - All content in Drupal is fully indexed and searchable at all
>   times if you take advantage of the
>   built in search module.
>
> ### User management
>
> **User authentication** - Users can register and authenticate locally or
>   using an external authentication
>   source like Jabber, Blogger,
>   LiveJournal or another Drupal website.
>   For use on an intranet, Drupal can
>   integrate with an LDAP server.detailed
>   information
>
> ### Content management
>
> **Polls** - Drupal comes with a poll module which enables admins and/or
>   users to create polls and show them on
>   various pages.detailed information
>
> **Templating** - Drupal's theme system separates content from presentation
>   allowing you to control the look and
>   feel of your Drupal site. Templates
>   are created from standard HTML and PHP
>   coding meaning that you don't have to
>   learn a proprietary templating
>   language.detailed information
>
> **Threaded comments** - Drupal provides a powerful threaded comment
>   model for enabling discussion on
>   published content. Comments are
>   hierarchical as in a newsgroup or
>   forum.detailed information
>
> **Version control** - Drupal's version control system tracks the details of
>   content updates including who changed
>   it, what was changed, the date and
>   time of changes made to your content
>   and more. Version control features
>   provide an option to keep a comment
>   log and enables you to roll-back
>   content to an earlier
>   version.screenshot
>
> ### Blogging
>
> **Blogger API support** - The Blogger API allows your Drupal site to be
>   updated by many different tools. This
>   includes non-web browser based tools
>   that provide a richer editing
>   environment.detailed information
>
> **Content syndication** - Drupal exports your site's content in RDF/RSS
>   format for others to gather. This lets
>   anyone with a News Aggregator browse
>   your Drupal sites feeds.detailed
>   information
>
> **News aggregator** - Drupal has a powerful built-in News Aggregator for
>   reading and blogging news from other
>   sites. The News Aggregator caches
>   articles to your MySQL database and
>   its caching time is user
>   configurable.detailed information
>
> **Permalinks** - All content created in Drupal has a permanent link or
>   "perma link" associated with it so
>   people can link to it freely without
>   fear of broken links.
>
> ### Platform
>
> **Apache or IIS, Unix / Linux / BSD / Solaris / Windows / Mac OS X support**
>   - Drupal was designed from the start to be multi-platform. Not only can you
>   use it with either Apache or Microsoft
>   IIS but we also have Drupal running on
>   Linux, BSD, Solaris, Windows, and Mac
>   OS X platforms.detailed information
>
> **Database independence** - While many of our users run Drupal with MySQL, we
>   knew that MySQL wasn't the solution
>   for everyone. Drupal is built on top
>   of a database abstraction layer that
>   enables you to use Drupal with MySQL
>   and PostgreSQL. Other SQL databases
>   can be supported by writing a
>   supporting database backend containing
>   fourteen functions and creating a
>   matching SQL database scheme.detailed
>   information
>
> **Multi-language** - Drupal is designed to meet the requirements of
>   an international audience and provides
>   a full framework to create a
>   multi-lingual website, blog, content
>   management system or community
>   application. All text can be
>   translated using a graphical user
>   interface, by importing existing
>   translations, or by integrating with
>   other translation tools such as the
>   GNU gettext.detailed information
>
> ### Administration and analysis
>
> **Analysis, Tracking and Statistics** - Drupal can print browser-based reports with information about
>   referrals, content popularity and how
>   visitors navigate your site.screenshot
>   . detailed information
>
> **Logging and Reporting** - All important activities and system events
>   are captured in an event log to be
>   reviewed by an administrator at a
>   later time.screenshot . detailed
>   information
>
> **Web based administration** - Drupal can be administered entirely using a
>   web browser, making it possible to
>   access it from around the world and
>   requires no additional software to be
>   installed on your computer.screenshot
>
> ### Community features
>
> **Discussion forums** - Full discussion forum features are built
>   into Drupal to create lively, dynamic
>   community sites.detailed information
>
> ### Performance and scalability
>
> **Caching** - The caching mechanism eliminates database queries increasing
>   performance and reducing the server's
>   load. Caching be tuned in real time
>   and many high-traffic sites have
>   performed very well under
>   load.detailed information

Comment: Thanks. But I already tried Drupal, but I can't able to understand all the settings here. Are there any free resources to learn Drupal?

Comment: @chanchal1987 — drupal.org, Drupal's official website, has plenty of learning resources and guides for all levels.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at http://openatrium.com/, a package based on Drupal.

Comment: Whitingx - thats exactly what i was looking for.. would you mind posting that to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12379/software-for-company-internal-website so i can give credit? :)